# CSS Only works locally in style attribute and not in an external stylesheet

Tags: html, css, styling

My css only works if I use the style attribute and it doesn't work with an external stylesheet

```css
.dateInput {
  text-align: center;
};
```

```html
<div class="dateInput">
  <label for="aplan-date">Date Of A-Plan:</label>
  <input type="date" id="aplan-date" name="aplan-date">
</div>
```

Chrome also shows the div as having no style
[image]

Comment: How are you importing the external stylesheet

Comment: I have `<link href="/styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` added in my head, i also forgot to mention that css isn't working for just this one div, it works in all other elements

Comment: works for me https://i.imgur.com/rSiAhfu.png

Comment: Consider adding an [mre]. Also, have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you included the stylesheet in your html file

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that i already have, css works for all other elements but not this one

Comment: Try with parent elements, like
. parentElement .dateInput {text-align: center;};

Comment: the only parent element this one has is body

Comment: In my case It's working

Comment: Show your full code

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra semicolon.

```css
.dateInput {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dateInput">
    <label for="aplan-date">Date Of A-Plan:</label>
    <input type="date" id="aplan-date" name="aplan-date">
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't change anything